# java code to format Jun 28, 2015T12:00:00 AM to date format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, date, datetime

Given an input date string, I wanted to parse the input date string. This input date format finally I wanted to change to some other date format. But Currently i am getting exception while parsing the input string itself.

```
    String startDateString = " Jun 28, 2015T12:00:00 AM";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss a");
        java.util.Date startDate;
        try {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
            String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
            System.out.println(newDateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Getting the following exception,

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " Jun 28, 2015T12:00:00 AM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at promo.json.parser.handler.Test.main(Test.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: you forgot the space before `Jun` in your format string. remove the space from the date string, or add it to your format...

Answer (score 5):

## Leading SPACE

Your input value `" Jun 28, 2015T12:00:00 AM"` does not match the parse format because of the leading SPACE character  before `Jun`.

Try editing the string to:

```
String startDateString = "Jun 28, 2015T12:00:00 AM";
```

Or call [`String::trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--):

```
startDateString.trim();
```

Comment: You might point out that there is a leading space in the starDateString as I need to compare you suggested value back against the ops a few times to pick it up ;)